# “Exporting” a Tributary example that makes use of the tributary object - d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am implementing the chart in d3.js, how can I "extract" a tributary example that is using the tributary object into HTML and Javascript code. Below is the code what i'm trying to do, but don't get success yet.

I have external JSON file `sample.json` which i need to use for chart data. Error shows that forEach is not a function. I am stuck what to do.

Please find my jsFiddle for whole code.

```js
// loading sample.json
d3.json("sample.json", function(sample2) {

//var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

// date manipulation to format UTC to js Date obj
sample2.forEach(function(d) { d.time = new Date(d.time * 1000); });

// helpers and constants
var margin = {"top": 50, "right": 100, "bottom": 56, "left": 50};
var width = 930 - margin.right - margin.left;
var height = 582 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var timeFormat = d3.time.format("%c");
var X = width/sample2.length*0.25;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="inlet.js"></script>
    <link src="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong with my code. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wLrdgt89/1/

Comment: well the problm is that you have not mentioned location of your sample.json the root location does not have it.

Comment: It's there on root location

Comment: your local instance root location..? when you run the code on your browser do you see any error in the network tab..? if yes what does that say.

Comment: on console it gives error , not in network tab

Comment: TypeError: sample2.forEach is not a function
 

sample2.forEach(function(d) { d.time = new Date(d.time * 1000); });

Comment: on root location i have files : inlet.js, sample.json, style.css, index.html

Comment: then it seems sample2 is not an array can you also post sample.json in the question

Comment: {"sample2": [
    {"time": 1387212120, "open": 368, "close": 275, "high": 380, "low": 231},
    {"time": 1387212130, "open": 330, "close": 350, "high": 389, "low": 310},
    {"time": 1387212570, "open": 395, "close": 253, "high": 438, "low": 213}
]}

Comment: yeah its not an array do this first line 
_d3.json("sample.json", function(sample2) { sample2= sample2.sample2_

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix these:

Problem:1

```
{"sample2": [ {"time": 1387212120, "open": 368, "close": 275, "high": 380, "low": 231}, {"time": 1387212130, "open": 330, "close": 350, "high": 389, "low": 310}, {"time": 1387212570, "open": 395, "close": 253, "high": 438, "low": 213} ]}
```

Your json is an object and not an Array so forEach will not work.
You need to do something like this:

```
d3.json("sample.json", function(sample2) { 
sample2= sample2.sample2
```

Problem2
Your html body has no svg so you need to append it:

```
var canvas = d3.select("svg")//this is wrong

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")//add svg to the body
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/wLrdgt89/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: One more thing that i'm also appending drop-down select box on selection of option from that my chart will regenerate.... my structure is creating in DOM but not showing on screen...any suggestions..  <select id="drop-down">
<option value="candle">candle</option>
<option value="line">line</option>
<option value="area">area</option>
</select>

Comment: it's a part of my problem